# Insert a blank row before zero

Tags: r

```
x<-c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
aaa<-data.frame(x)
```

How to insert a blank row before zero? When the first row is zero，do not add blank row. Thank you.

Result:

```
0
1
1
.
0
1
1
1
.     
0
1
1
```

Comment: x<-c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1);
y<-c("a","b","c","d","e","g","h","i","j","k");
aaa<-data.frame(x,y);
rm(x);
rm(y);      Here I want to get dataframe aaa with  blank row. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Below we used dot but you can replace "." with NA or "" or something else depending on what you want.

**1)** We can use `Reduce` and `append`:

```
Append <- function(x, y) append(x, ".", y - 1)
data.frame(x = Reduce(Append, setdiff(rev(which(aaa$x == 0)), 1), init = aaa$x))
```

**2) gsub** Another possibility is to convert to a character string, use `gsub` and convert back:

```
data.frame(x = strsplit(gsub("(.)0", "\\1.0", paste(aaa$x, collapse = "")), "")[[1]])
```

**3)** We can create a two row matrix in which the first row is dot before each 0 and NA otherwise.  Then unravel it to a vector and use na.omit to remove the NA values.

```
data.frame(x = na.omit(c(rbind(replace(ifelse(aaa$x == 0, ".", NA), 1, NA), aaa$x))))
```

**4)** We can lapply over aaa$x[-1] outputting c(".", 9) or 1.  Unlist that and insert aaa$x[1] back in.  No packages are used.

```
repl <- function(x) if (!x) c(".", 0) else 1
data.frame(x = c(aaa$x[1], unlist(lapply(aaa$x[-1], repl))))
```

**5)** Create a list of all but the first element and replace the 0's in that list with `c(".", 0)` .  Unlist that and insert the first element back in.  No packages are used.

```
L <- as.list(aaa$x[-1])
L[x[-1] == 0] <- list(c(".", 0))
data.frame(x = c(aaa$x[1], unlist(L)))
```

**6)** Assuming `aaa` has two columns where the second column is character (NOT factor).  Append a row of dots to `aaa` and then create an index vector using `unlist` and `Map` to access the appropriate row of the extended `aaa`.

```
aaa <- data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1), y = letters[1:10],
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nr <- nrow(aaa); nc <- ncol(aaa)
fun <- function(ix, x) if (!is.na(x) & x == 0 & ix > 1) c(nr + 1, ix) else ix
rbind(aaa,  rep(".", nc))[unlist(Map(fun, 1:nr, aaa$x)), ]
```

If we did want to have `y` be factor then note that we can't just add a dot to a factor if it is not a level of that factor so there is the question of what levels the factor can have.  To get around that let us add an NA rather than a dot to the factor.  Then we get the following which is the same except that `aaa` has been redefined so that `y` is a factor, we no longer need `nc` since we are assuming 2 columns and `rep(...)` in the last line is replaced with `c(".", NA)`.

```
aaa <- data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1), y = letters[1:10])

nr <- nrow(aaa)
fun <- function(ix, x) if (!is.na(x) & x == 0 & ix > 1) c(nr + 1, ix) else ix
rbind(aaa,  c(".", NA))[unlist(Map(fun, 1:nr, aaa$x)), ]
```

Comment: 0
1
1
NA
0
1
1
1
NA   
0
1
1  If here . is NA, may you give me the simple method, thank you very much.

Comment: Assuming the vector shown is to be the input then alternative (1) in the answer works.

Comment: x<-c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1);
y<-c("a","b","c","d","e","g","h","i","j","k");
aaa<-data.frame(x,y);
rm(x);
rm(y);      Here I want to get dataframe aaa with  blank row. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that y is a character column, NOT factor, we have added 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
ind = with(aaa, ifelse(x == 0 & seq_along(x) > 1, 2, 1))
d = aaa[rep(1:NROW(aaa), ind), , drop = FALSE]
transform(d, x = replace(x, sequence(ind) == 2, NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility may be:

```
aaa %>%
 uncount(ifelse(row_number() > 1 & x == 0, 2, 1)) %>%
 mutate(x = ifelse(x == 0 & lag(x == 1, default = first(x)), NA_integer_, x))

    x
1   0
2   1
3   1
4  NA
5   0
6   1
7   1
8   1
9  NA
10  0
11  1
12  1
```

It is not adding a blank row as you have a numeric vector. Instead, it is adding a row with NA. If you need a blank row, you can convert it into a character vector and then replace NA with blank.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(aaa)[,  .(x = if(x[.N] == 1) c(x, NA) else x), rleid(x)][-.N, .(x)]
#     x
# 1:  0
# 2:  1
# 3:  1
# 4: NA
# 5:  0
# 6:  1
# 7:  1
# 8:  1
# 9: NA
#10:  0
#11:  1
#12:  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data.frame(x = unname(unlist(by(aaa$x,cumsum(aaa==0),c,'.'))))
   x
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  .
5  0
6  1
7  1
8  1
9  .
10 0
11 1
12 1
13 .
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
 aaa <- data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1), y = letters[1:10])
 aaa$ind = with(aaa, ifelse(x == 0 & seq_along(x) > 1, 2, 1))
 aaa<-aaa[rep(1:nrow(aaa), aaa$ind), ,]
 aaa[(aaa$ind== 2 & !grepl(".1",rownames(aaa))),]<-NA
 aaa$ind<- NULL 
 aaa
      x    y
 1    0    a
 2    1    b
 3    1    c
 4   NA <NA>
 4.1  0    d
 5    1    e
 6    1    f
 7    1    g
 8   NA <NA>
 8.1  0    h
 9    1    i
 10   1    j
```